# I'd like to ask you a question about the Android Gradle Build Error

Tags: gradle

I want to solve the Android Gradle Build error message.
Please let me know if you know how to solve this problem.

This is the current setup

Compile Sdk Version
27

Build Tools Version
27.0.3

build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.1.1'
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-bin.zip

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':android:classpath'.
  >   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.1.1.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.pom
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.jar
  > - file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.pom
  > - file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.jar
  > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.pom
  > - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.jar
  > - https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.pom
  > - https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.pom
  > - http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/com/android/tools/build/gradle/5.1.1/gradle-5.1.1.pom

Required by:
         project :android

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 0):

The android build tool version is wrong:
Currently, due to [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin), the latest android build tool version is 3.4.1, so you should use `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'`.

Before:

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.1.1'
```

After:

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```